# To write the value fetched from the textbox into the column of Excel through POI using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have fetched the value from the textbox and stored in a string. Now i want to write this value stored in string into the column named as 'Username' in the excel file.
E.G: Fetched the Username from the textbox as 'Test1' and want to write this in the column 'Username' of the Excel. I am using POI to write excel file using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

hi please implement the logic like below

public static void writeExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName,String[] dataToWrite) throws IOException{

```
        //Create a object of File class to open xlsx file
        File file =    new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
        //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook Workbook = null;
        //Find the file extension by spliting file name in substing and getting only extension name
        String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
        //Check condition if the file is xlsx file
        if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){
        //If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
        Workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        }

        //Check condition if the file is xls file
        else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")){
            //If it is xls file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
            Workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        }  

    //Read excel sheet by sheet name    
    Sheet sheet = Workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    //Get the current count of rows in excel file
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
    //Get the first row from the sheet
    Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
    //Create a new row and append it at last of sheet
    Row newRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount+1);
    //Create a loop over the cell of newly created Row
    for(int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++){
        //Fill data in row
        Cell cell = newRow.createCell(j);
        cell.setCellValue(dataToWrite[j]);

    }
    //Close input stream
    inputStream.close();
    //Create an object of FileOutputStream class to create write data in excel file
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    //write data in the excel file
    Workbook.write(outputStream);
    //close output stream
    outputStream.close();
    }
```

Now call the above in main method like below

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            String valueToWrite = "test 1";
            //Create an object of current class
            WriteExcelFile objExcelFile = new WriteExcelFile();
            //Write the file using file name , sheet name and the data to be filled
            objExcelFile.writeExcel(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\excelExportAndFileIO","ExportExcel.xlsx","ExcelDemo",valueToWrite);

        }
```

Comment: @Rajnish- what should be included in the (filePath+"\\"+fileName): Only the File name ("C:\\Users\\Nishant\\Downloads\\TestData.xls") like this only will be added

Comment: your path to the file + "\\" + excel sheet name (dataSheet.xls)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know column number of "Username" column in the excel sheet. Once you know that then it will be easy to write value of String that you captured from webpage. You can take below approach -

```
        File excelFile = new File("C:\\path\\of\\excel\\file\\excel.xlsx");
        String cellNo = 3; //column number of "UserName" column
        String rowNo = 1; // row number 
        String userName = "Test1"; // username fetched from textbox

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNo); 
        row.createCell(cellNo).setCellValue(userName);
        fis.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
```

This is very simple approach just for this purpose and is not generalized one for any other task.
You can take a look at [simple script that reads from a excel sheet and writes back to same excel sheet using Apache POI, here.](http://selenium-coding.blogspot.in/2016/05/reading-and-writting-data-from-xlsx.html)

Regards,
Punkaaj